# How to speed up data import with PHP and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm importing a big CSV file (500M, ~2.000.000 lines, 50 columns) into a PostgreSQL (14.2) table using Laravel 9 (PHP 8.1), it takes around one hour on a dedicated server (Ubuntu 22.04) with 4 CPU and 8G of RAM.

During the import, I can see with `htop` that only two CPUs are being used and never at full speed:
[image]

Is there a way to make a better usage of the server in order to speed up this daily import ?

Comment: It always depends on **how** you import your stuff. Please share some code. Apart from that, you might want to have a look at `COPY table FROM csv CSV HEADER;` command.

Comment: @membersound I understand but whatever is the code doing, why PHP or PostgreSQL only use 2 CPUs instead of 4 and why only 1/4 of each CPU ?

Comment: You can also use pg_put_line in combination with COPY to speed things up. 2 million lines of CSV should be a matter of seconds, not hours. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-put-line.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to use more than a single CPU core is to open several database connecions and use them in parallel. However, even with a single core you can be much faster if you

- run many inserts in a single database transaction
- use prepared statements to reduce planning overhead
- have as few indexes as possible
- use `COPY` rather than `INSERT` for bulk loading